# Caffe: what's the difference between train_test.prototxt and deploy.prototxt?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

In pertained models like GoogleNet
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet

we can see two .prototxt file describing the network, what's the **differences** between them?

> [deploy.txt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt) and [train_test.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt)

My key question is , in python interface, why can I only use the former one? That is to say:

```
model_def = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt'

model_weights = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_googlenet/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Net(model_def,model_weights,caffe.TEST)
```

this code runs correct while:

```
model_def = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt'

model_weights = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_googlenet/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Net(model_def,model_weights,caffe.TEST)
```

this does not. and it gives out error information:

```
layer {
  name: "inception_4e/relu_5x5_reduce"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "inception_4e/5x5_reduce"
  top: "inception_4e/5x5_reduce"
}
layer {
I0805 10:15:13.698256 30930 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
I0805 10:15:13.698444 30930 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer data
I0805 10:15:13.698465 30930 net.cpp:408] data -> data
I0805 10:15:13.698514 30930 net.cpp:408] data -> label
F0805 10:15:13.699956   671 db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

Why? what's the differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`train_val.prototxt` is used in training whereas `deploy.prototxt` is used in inference.

`train_val.prototxt` has the information of where the training data is located. In your case, it contains the path for an lmdb file which contains the training data.

`deploy.prototxt` contains the information regarding the input size but it does not contain any information regarding the input itself. So you can pass any image with that size as input to it and do inference.

When you load `train_val.prototxt` it looks for the training data file mentioned in it. You are getting an error because it is unable to find it.

Tip: When doing inference, it is better to use `deploy.prototxt`.